# Self-evaluation: how is the site working out?

Tags: discussion

At Stack Exchange, we stop in now and then to check on how each site is doing. As part of this, we like to take a few questions and compare them against the wisdom of The Greater Internet. This gives us a pretty good idea of which sites are progressing, and which are struggling... But it doesn't do much for you.

So let's try something a little different... Below you'll find ten questions, picked at random from Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair. Take a look at each, and try to find the answer on Google - then compare what you find to the answer(s) given here.

1. [Setting timer for central locking for forgetful owners](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/setting-timer-for-central-locking-for-forgetful-owners)
2. [What skills does one need to have to get started in auto body repair?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/what-skills-does-one-need-to-have-to-get-started-in-auto-body-repair)
3. [Audi 06 - Replace Thermostat](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2101/audi-06-replace-thermostat)
4. [Loose Handbrake?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/loose-handbrake)
5. [What's the name of the little plastic bolt (?) that is used by a passanger/driver to lock the door from the inside?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/whats-the-name-of-the-little-plastic-bolt-that-is-used-by-a-passanger-drive)
6. [Honda CVT Multimatic Gearbox oil-change frequency](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/honda-cvt-multimatic-gearbox-oil-change-frequency)
7. [Ford Focus steering wheel vibration and noise from front right wheel4](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/ford-focus-steering-wheel-vibration-and-noise-from-front-right-wheel4)
8. [Test Gasoline for Water Content](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/test-gasoline-for-water-content)
9. [My 2007 Jeep Commander is blowing hot air into the cabin even though the temperature is set to cool](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/my-2007-jeep-commander-is-blowing-hot-air-into-the-cabin-even-though-the-tempera)
10. [Racing Fuel (100 Octane Rating) - Better than Premium?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/racing-fuel-100-octane-rating-better-than-premium)

How does this site stack up against the various message boards, forums, and answer sites that populate the Web? Post your thoughts below...

Comment: I've responded to point five if that helps organize the response.

Comment: Good stuff so far, thanks Bob

Answer (score 4):

I'll take number five since I answered that question.  [Here's the standard google query](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=What%27s%20the%20name%20of%20the%20little%20plastic%20bolt%20%28?%29%20that%20is%20used%20by%20a%20passanger/driver%20to%20lock%20the%20door%20from%20the%20inside?).  If you look at the results, they're all over the map in terms of door parts and plastic bits.  There's very little that Google can do for what is, plainly, a fairly complex natural language problem.

In contrast, I was able to interpret what he was looking for and come up with a reasonable facsimile of an eBay query that provided the OP with a pictorial confirmation that I was at least in the right ball park as well as a potential source for replacement parts.

In sum, Reed turned up with a pretty simple question for humans to understand and seemed very satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 3):

Some commentary on question eight (one that I didn't participate in):

The excepted answer is a solo and it has a short summary of the fuel separation procedure.  However, there's a lot more meat in the comments themselves, including a quick summary of the hygroscopic nature of ethanol.

So, I'd advise some judicious editing of the answer but it's not critical.  The content is A+.  The OP clearly came in with an "I'm not sure what to do" question and walked away with plenty of actionable information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think these are the best questions to use for an evaluation. This site has the potential to blow the doors off all the UBB powered model enthusiast sites (modelforum.com/net/org) where you have to search through 10+ 20 page threads to find the one or three really good answers

Comment: well, that may be - but the point of this exercise is to evaluate a random sample, to give us a feel for how the site is doing as a whole. If you have certain questions that you feel are exemplary, don't hesitate to post another thread here on Meta to highlight them - or better yet, show them to your friends!